# Recursive QuickSort multiple bugs

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort

I have been trying to fix this recursive quick sort program for about three days now and I believe it has bugs in it because it sorts smaller size arrays but wrongly sorts larger arrays.

The code sorts an array from `a[start] to a[end]` using the median-of-three technique. I believe the problem lies in the partitioning. Please have a look

```
    import java.util.*;
public class QuickSort
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int [] arr = {6,4,1,14, 13,20,7,10,9,2,17};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    quickSort(arr, 0,arr.length-1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    System.out.println("is the array sorted? " + isSorted(arr));
  }
public static void quickSort(int[] a, int start, int end)
  {
    if(end-start > 0) //base case for zero or one element? 
    {
        int pivotPosn = partition(a,start,end);
        quickSort(a,start, pivotPosn-1);
        quickSort(a,pivotPosn+1, end);
    }

  }
   /***
   * swap - Swaps two values in an array.
   ***/
  private static void swap(int [] a, int index1, int index2)
  {
    int temp = a[index1];
    a[index1] = a[index2];
    a[index2] = temp;
  }
  private static boolean isSorted(int [] a)
  {

    int i = a.length;
    boolean result = true;
    for(int j = 1; j<i; j++)
    {
      if(a[j-1] > a[j])
      {
        result = false;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  private static int medianOfThreeIndex(int [] a, int start, int end)
  {
    int mid= start + (end-start)/2; //find the middle of the array

    int vs = a[start];
    int vm = a[mid];
    int ve = a[end];

    if (vs >= vm  && vm >= ve)
    {
      return mid;
    }
    else if (vm >= vs  && vs >= ve)
    {
      return start;
    }
    else
    {
      return end;
    }
  }
  private static int partition(int [] a, int start, int end)
  {
    int boundary,pivot,pivotPosn;
    pivotPosn = medianOfThreeIndex(a,start,end);
    pivot = a[pivotPosn];
    boundary = start;

    swap(a,pivotPosn,end);//moving pivot to the right
    for(int curr = start+1; curr<=end;curr++)
    {
      if(a[curr]<pivot)
      {
        boundary++;
        swap(a,boundary,curr);
      }
    }
    swap(a,end,boundary); //swap pivot value back to its final place
    return boundary;
  }
}
```

Output is `[6, 4, 1, 9, 7, 13, 14, 10, 17, 20, 2]`
i do not know what i am doing wrong :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a couple of errors, the main one being that I don't think you've quite understood what the median of three bit should be doing and where to use it.  In particular - it should be used to select the pivot, not to do any swapping on the array.  I'll assume your swap method works correctly.

You could first forget about the median of three pivot selection and get the main bit of your program working.  The median of three pivot selection is only to improve performance against choosing, say, the start of the array as the pivot.  So, let's alter your code to do that first:

```
private static int partition(int [] a, int start, int end)
{
    int boundary,pivotPosn, pivot,bigStart;

    pivotPosn = start;
    pivot = a[pivotPosn];
    boundary = start;

    //Got rid of bigStart - it's not needed...
    swap(a,pivotPos,end); //Move your pivot value to the "right" or end of array

    // Note - it is fine to store the pivot at the "left" or start as
    // the OP originally did - in which case the following for
    // loop should run from start+1 to end inclusive and the 
    // boundary++ would come before the swap.

    for(int curr = start; curr<end;curr++)
    {
        if(a[curr]<pivot)
        {

            swap(a,boundary,curr);
            boundary++;
        }
    }
    swap(a,end,boundary); //swap your pivot value back to its final place
    return boundary;
}
```

Then look at your quicksort method.  Remember we're ignoring medianOfThree for now.  You catch an edge case you don't really need to - the 2 member array.  Far simpler would be:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] a, int start, int end)
{
    if(end-start > 0) //base case for zero or one element? already 
    {
        int pivotPosn = partition(a,start,end);
        quickSort(a,start, pivotPosn-1);
        quickSort(a,pivotPosn+1, end);
    }
}
```

With that, it will work :)

However - you might want to go back to medianOfThree.  Remember where we put `pivotPosn = start`?

Alter that to `pivotPosn = medianOfThree(a,start,end);`  (or anything you like, as long as it's within the array - play around).

medianOfThree then needs to return the index of the median value out of start, middle and end of array.  I suggest altering your method as so (not the most compact, but easy to read):

```
private static int medianOfThreeIndex(int [] a, int start, int end)
{
    int mid= start + (end-start)/2; //find the middle of the array

    int vs = a[start];
    int vm = a[mid];
    int ve = a[end];

    if (vs >= vm  && vm >= ve)
    {
        return mid;
    }
    else if (vm >= vs  && vs >= ve)
    {
        return start;
    }
    else
    {
        return end;
    }

}
```

With that - you're done.  I looked around for a tutorial in case you're not clear on the algorithm and found [the Wikipedia article on this is pretty good.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Comment: where you said to change pivotPosn to  `pivotPosn = medianOfThreeIndex(a,start,end);` was that in the partition method? because i did that and also modified my code based on this and still am getting faulty results :(

Comment: here is my input 

`[6, 4, 1, 14, 13, 20, 7, 10, 9, 2, 17]`
and her is the output 
`[6, 4, 1, 9, 7, 13, 14, 10, 17, 20, 2]`

Comment: You know what?  I've just gone back to your original too and I think your real issue is with your `if(!(isSorted(a)))` line.  That (I assume) is checking if the whole of `a` is sorted (although you don't show code for `isSorted` or `swap`. Actually, if you remove that, or say `if (a[start] > a[end])` in its place, I think your original program, although unconventionally implemented, will work.  It's still the case that your medianOfThree is unconventional - you only get the median once, then use the start value as the pivot always.  But that's OK, not optimal, but OK.

Comment: If you can confirm the above - I'll edit my answer to take account of that too.

Comment: i have updated my code and edited the original post. that is how my code looks now.

Comment: OK -  I see I've made a typo and copied some of your original into my answer and mixed two boundary conditions.  I'm really sorry - I don't know how that happened.  The problems are two-fold : your `boundary++` is before you do the swap, it should be after. and the for loop should run from `for(int curr = start; curr<end;curr++)` instead of what you've got now.  The other order is from your original, where you "store" the pivot value at index `start` instead of `end`.  For my interest - can you verify your original works if you take out the `isSorted` test? Or has that version gone forever?

Comment: oh the modifications worked. for the original version, i took out the `isSorted` test and it still did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems strange to me. Have a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html
The code there seems clearer to me.